# Remove showing the parameters setting for a function in PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm

I am trying to find the setting which disable showing the parameters of any function as shown below, I couldn't find it and it is very confusing and annoying.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Settings->Editor->General->Appearance and uncheck "Show parameter name hints"

I find this function extremely useful ... but yes. That is the way to disable it.